# Simple way to backup / restore database in SQLite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I was wondering what the simplest and easiest way to backup / restore a database on SQLite 3 is?  I have read around and there are lots of articles detailing methods for complicated situations, but I am struggling to find a basic procedure.

I have one simple database on a site which is basically a news reel of a company's recent activities.  The site is just about to be deployed and will have new posts added on a roughly daily basis.  I am hoping to write a number of posts before the site goes online, then upload the database onto the live server.  From then on, new posts will be added online but it would be nice to have a backup in case something goes wrong.

So, essentially my question is: 
Is there a simple way to backup a database in SQLite3 and also to upload a database?  I am aware that I could possibly use `seeds` as a way to upload the data initially, but ideally i would rather just copy the development database (if possible...) and upload it onto the production server.

Apologies for my ignorance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nice thing about sqlite3 is that it's a file-based database exclusively. So long as you can prevent an application from using the database for a bit, backing up and restoring is as simple as copying the database file itself.

Comment: So I would literally copy the development.sqlite3, rename and put on the live server? I can guarantee the database is not going to be used as only i have permission to use it

Comment: If the app is not running then this will work reliably. Otherwise you might have some locking issues. But I figure that we try to solve the problem in the easiest way possible before we try more complicated solutions.

Answer (score 9):

I would read the backup documentation [here](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html). There are some potential risks in doing file copies, but especially for the initial launch, this approach would be fine. I have done this on a couple of low traffic sites for a number of years and never run into any issues.

Comment: I will have a look into this too, thanks, to enable the backup to be done while the site is running.